# How do I run a function with arguments in a subprocess without calling it directly?

Tags: python, function, python-multiprocessing

Why does my `while True:` loop stop, when I press 'A'? I want to run a function when I press A, keep it running, and be able to run another function when I press A again (without having to wait the first one completing fully).

The code keeps printing "running" as it's supposed to at the start, but when I press 'A' on my keyboard, it starts the function, and does not print "running" anymore. How do I fix this?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

process_count = 0

def testfunc1(number):
    for i in range(50):
        print(number)
        time.sleep(1)

while True:
    print("running")
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        process_count += 1
        print("process_count:", process_count)
        Process(target=testfunc1(process_count)).start()
```

Comment: You called `testfunc1` in your main process and passed it's result `None` as the `target` argument to `Process` constructor. Try `Process(target=testfunc1, args=(process_count, )).start()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class

Comment: It should continue to print "running" after 50 seconds...

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo
hey thanks that works! for debugging purposes i removed the print("running") line, but the testfunc1 is not printing anything? its supposed  to print the given number 50 times. pic here https://imgur.com/VK4fmbr

Comment: It prints the desired output if I run it in the normal Python interpreter. Perhaps some IDLE quirk is causing the issue.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo so you got it to print "1" every second, and when pressing A again, it prints "1" & "2" every  second? if A is pressed yet again, it prints "1" & "2" & "3" every second?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```py
import time
import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process


process_count = 0


def testfunc1(number):
    print(number)
    for i in range(50):
        print(number)
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    global process_count
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
            process_count += 1
            print("process_count:", process_count)

            for i in range(process_count):
                Process(target=testfunc1, args=[process_count]).start()
        time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note: You were calling the function directly. By modifying `target=testfunc1(process_count)` to `target=testfunc1, args=[process_count]` you can pass arguments to a function that runs as a thread.

You can also pass named arguments with the `kwargs={"arg1": True, "arg2": 123}` argument

Also note, that before creating any new processes the current process must have finished its bootstrapping phase, otherwise you will get a RuntimeError. To achieve that, your code should be wrapped in a `if __name__ == "__main__"` statement.

Comment: Hey, i edited my code a little bit, right now they do run on seperate processes which is good, but its not printing anything? is it because its printing it in the other processes window? https://imgur.com/DWCAxAw

Comment: You need to wrap your code under `if __name__ == "__main__":`. I edited the answer with full code, hope it works